# MyBatis foreach typeException

Tags: java, spring, db2, mybatis

Not very sure as to the syntax of the foreach condition. Since an array is used, collection should be my key and item should be my value. However it says #2 is null. May I ask why?

I have an array of integers and DAOMap extends HashMap<Object, Object>

Student OBject details contains two variables

```
    private int studentID;
    private String contextID;
```

```
    int[] slotID  // array of integer
    StudentLogin login // Object of student login.

    final DAOMap params = new DAOMap("MASS DELETE");
    params.put("slotID", slotID);
    params.put("updatedBy", login.getStudentID);


    mapper.massDelete(params); // Calling of the sql by passing in array of integers.
```

In mapper.xml

```
 <update id="massDelete" parameterType="DAOMap">
        UPDATE ${schemaName}SLOT SET
            UPDATEDBY=#{updatedBy},
            DTUPDATED=current timestamp
        WHERE ID in
        <foreach collection="slotID" item="item" index="index"   separator="," 
    open = "(" close=")" >
                #{item}
            </foreach>
            
    </update>
```

Server logs

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='ID', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #2 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #2 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][1091][10824][3.64.106] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance [I@d2fe03dc is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: Which version of MyBatis do you use? Also, there are three variables (ID, timeslotID, slotID) in your sample code and their relationship is unclear. Is it a typo? Please edit the question so that we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi ave apologies for the typo. I have edited it. I am using 2.1.4

Comment: Assuming that `DAOMap` is a subclass of `HashMap` or alike, everything looks fine. I made an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-65592472) for you. Try it yourself and see what's different.

Comment: @user14949876: the issue is most likely with the parameters you are sending, not with the mapping. You are not showing any code there, just random pieces and `....`. People can't help you if they have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: Noted let me test your demo ave @bogdan let me edit update the post again.